# Blazor WASM stuck on "Authorizing..." and "Completing login..."

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, blazor-client-side, .net-5

After upgrading to .Net 5.0 my blazor WASM app started getting stuck on "Authorizing..." (it gets stuck when the user was already logged in, first load with redirect to login screen works fine, so I have to clear the cache if I want it to work) and "Completing login..." (with a URL like https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback?code=51FEF78805049242F1092A249B1746393790AE956B1FC2136092AE0924B3FB42&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20MyApp.WebAPI&state=e8bffbd2b93f44dc8a261cf6d65c6165&session_state=eE0yRtJI0fkjptvZSIfiUsvuHAQoyNStmS_kv--Wcv0.DCACB551F4CC63841C2615456DD4B9BF) - if I go to localhost:5001 after it got stuck on "Completing login..." I am finally logged in.

Initially it was working fine on most modern computers and the issue was only visible on slow computers (~8 year old laptop for instance). However, while I tried to understand the issue and fix it, I managed to brake it completely on my developer laptop as well, where the main branch still works mostly fine.

Creating a new ASP.Net Core app with authentication with IdentityServer4 works just fine, no issues there.

My issue looks similar to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26195 - however, I'm using only IdentityServer4 and I don't see any exceptions in the developer console.

I tried to reduce the code to a bare minimum, so here is the `Program.cs`:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

    builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizer>(serviceProvider =>
    {
        var factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
        return factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
    });
    builder.Services.AddLocalization();

    builder.Services
        .AddBlazorise()
        .AddBootstrapProviders();

    builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);

    var host = builder.Build();

    host.Services.UseBootstrapProviders();

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

the `App.razor`:

```xml
@inject IStringLocalizer S

<ThemeManager>
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
                        {
                            <p>@S["You don't have enough permissions to access this page."]</p>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <RedirectToLogin />
                        }
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <NotFoundError>
                    </NotFoundError>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</ThemeManager>
```

The `MainLayout.razor`:

```xml
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.LayoutComponentBase

<header>
</header>

<main>
    @Body
</main>
```

The `Authentication.razor`:

```xml
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@if (Action == "logged-out")
{
    <RedirectToLogin RedirectBackToRoot="true"></RedirectToLogin>
}

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string? Action { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, that it just gets stuck and I don't even see what could be wrong. The one dependency I have here is on https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise - however, I added the same dependency also to the new application, and that one still works.

Any idea how I could identify the issue?

Comment: You should first make sure that the update was done correctly. You mentioned that you have new project created - so open them on a split screen and compare them, see if you missed something when moving from the old version.

Comment: Thx, I did try that. I tried reducing my wasm project down to the same code as the new template. I've also analyzed the underlying http calls and those look alike as well.

Comment: Spent lot of hours with this issue. Restarting computer helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was, that the reference of the JS library [pace.js](https://codebyzach.github.io/pace/) broke the authentication. A new version of the library was released (and automatically updated) around the same time, we upgraded to .Net 5.0 so not sure if it was a .Net 5 issue or the library issue.

Comment: This answer would have been impossible to find based on my currently formulated question, but still might be relevant for others in the future, so I'd keep it

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced hanging during login but years after this post.  Mine happened with .NET 6. I noticed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer was version 6.0.8 and that version had just been released last week.  I downgraded to 6.0.7 and the hanging went away.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was gone after I added the following to my Blazor project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" />
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

similar to the issues described here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49956

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in dotnet 8 blazor wasm project... I did the following steps..

1. Deleted `bin` and `obj` folder in blazor wasm `.csproj`.
2. Added the following code in blazor wasm `.csproj`

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

3. Published the project.

Reference - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49956#issuecomment-1992857288

Now all works fine.